# Making a newline in Transifex online editor

Tags: transifex

I'm trying to make a newline in the [Transifex](https://transifex.com) online editor but I can't figure how this can be done.
When I just press Enter, the editor didn't seems to make a new line like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiqHJ.png) (sorry, I can't attach images to my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the web editor in Transifex keep in mind that the "⏎" character denotes a new line. So when you see it in the source string just go ahead and hit the  or  key at the same point in the translation. The symbol is not seen but since you press Enter or Return the editor adds the expected newline.

You can check it in [Transifex's documentation](http://support.transifex.com/customer/portal/articles/1380532-instructions-on-software-localization#new-lines) too.